# How to copy images in wwwroot, or how to refer them?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, bundle

I have a very primitive UI app, .netcore with jquery and images folder. I have this configuration because we have a machine which supports only javascript/jquery. After I run project from VS 2017, images urls don't work (because is looking in wwwroot folder).
How to copy images in wwwroot, or export them somehow like bundles for example?

Comment: You may want to read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) article on serving static files.

Answer (score 1):

If you have files located in another folder which is not part of wwwroot you could add it as your static files.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles(); // For the wwwroot folder

    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "PathToYourFolder")),
        RequestPath = "/PathToYourFolder"
    });
}
```

Access the images:

```
<img src="~/PathToYourFolder/first.svg" alt="your image" />
```

For js,css files you could use bundle. Install

```
Install-Package BuildBundlerMinifier -Version 2.8.391
```

After that create json file - `bundleconfig.json` in the root of your web project

```
[ 
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/myjs.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "FolderOfYourJS/yourJs.js"
    ]
  }

]
```

This will create on every build myjs.min.js file in your js folder in wwwroot.

Answer (score 0):

This not working:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
I tried with the tilde but nothing... I think the only way is to have a cmd command when build project which will copy images in wwwroot...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
ajax.get('/Console/api/something', function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $('.data-container')
            .append(createTaksLine(data, i));
    }
    })
})
```

createTaksLine() return a string which is in html format.